# Replace main menu's first and second items A element with SPAN

Tags: jquery

My solution below is almost working:

```
$('#main-menu > ul > li:nth-child(1) a, #main-menu > ul > li:nth-child(2) a').replaceWith(function() {
    return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>'
});
```

It replaces `<a>` with a `<span>` but it replaces submenus elements also. I don't want that. Here's an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gallex/vh3dnmv4/)

Comment: So just add another `>`  to the selector? `... li:nth-child(n) > a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `>` before `<a>` as using this way `#main-menu > ul > li:nth-child(1) a` means all the `<a>` in `<li>`. Adding `>` will restrict it two first child only.

```js
$('#main-menu > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a,#main-menu > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a').replaceWith(function() {
return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">item5</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make it even more compact using `nth-child(-n+2)` to select first three elements.

```
$('#main-menu > ul > li:nth-child(-n+2) > a').replaceWith(function() {
return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>'
});
```